# developing an app to send messages over WiFi between users

Tags: android, chat, android-tablayout

How can I make the "sending messages" tab? How can I send messages over WiFi in tab among users? For e.g. the Facebook, Skype and other chat apps use tabs to send messages.

Here is my code for the tabs:

```
 public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);

//        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        int[] tabIcons = {
                R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_message_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_schedule_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24dp,
        };

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            // return null to display only the icon
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be able to chat between two android devices using WiFi connectivity. There is an API called **Wifi P2P**. More information can be found on [android developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html). It is only available for Android 4.0+ devices.

You can also use UDP Multicast which is available since API level 1. See [android developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/MulticastSocket.html).

Note: UDP does not guarantee data delivery(packages can be lost), so use UDP multicast for device discovery, and open up a TCP connection for data that requires guaranteed delivery. TCP listening port can be advertised via UDP multicast so that everyone can connect with each other over TCP.

There are third party tools that can do most of the work for you. For e.g. learn from this [github repository](https://github.com/life0fun/wifi-direct-chat).

Comment: can you provide me with the code to make the message tab.